# Selecting next field on press enter using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html form and whenever `enter` is pressed the next field is selected.
here is a code.

```js
 $(document).on("keydown","input",function(event) {
     if (event.which === 13) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).nextAll("input").eq(0).focus();
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>Medical Record No.</td><td><input type="text" name="labNo" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Age/sex </td><td><input type="text" name="age" />
        <select id="age">
         <option value="Year">Year</option>
         <option value="Month">Month</option>
        </select>
        <select id="sex">
         <option value="Male">Male</option>
         <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Phone </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="" value="-,-" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="patBtn" value="Save (S)" accesskey="s" />
        <input type="reset" value="Set Default (D)" accesskey="d" />
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table> 
    </form>
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work no matter the html structure

```
$(document).on("keydown","input",function(event) {
if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var position = $(this).index('input');
    $("input").eq(position+1).focus();
}
 });
```

also for select:

```
$(document).on("keydown, keyup","input, select",function(event) {
if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var position = $(this).index('input, select');
    $("input, select").eq(position+1).focus();
}
 });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xh0m7pzu/1/

Comment: how can it go on `select` option also. @A_funs

Comment: actually I changed it, added keyup as well seems to be working in all browsers now

Comment: Did you try the js fiddle? what browser? You need both keyup and keydown as code above

Comment: works perfectly for me in chrome, safari and firefox

Comment: Not here, chrome version Version 38.0.2125.111 m

Comment: 38.0.2125.111 here, not sure about the m

Answer (score 1):

Try following script

```
$(document).on("keydown","input",function(event) {
    debugger;
    if (event.which === 13) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents("tr").next().find("input").focus();
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L0kka2me/)**